# My Accumulable is not shown in the Spark Web UI

Tags: apache-spark

I created a `case class A` and try to add a new Accumulable to Spark:

```
sc.accumulable(A(), "My accumulable description")
```

Now when Spark is running I cannot see my `Accumulable[A, B]` in the Spark Web UI. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible reason is that you did not implement `equals` method for `A` correctly. Spark relies on correct implementation of `equals` at least when it tries to find out whether your Accumulable was updated. An example of the comparison can be found in `DAGScheduler.scala:updateAccumulators` in this line of code:

```
if (acc.name.isDefined && partialValue != acc.zero) {
```

where `partialValue` is updated value of the Accumulable and `acc.zero` is initial value for the same Accumulable